# How to modify citation and database entry for conf. proceeding with the iet bibliography style?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

[image]The `iet.bst` file is not providing the appropriate citation for conference proceedings and database entry. How do I modify it?

The `iet.bst` file under section 2.6.5 on the webpage which I am using:
http://digital-library.theiet.org/journals/author-guide

The bib entries are:

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{byang,
        author={B. Yang and D. Hartung and K. Simoens and C. Busch},
        booktitle={IEEE International Conference on Biometrics: 
        Theory Applications and Systems (BTAS)},
        title={Dynamic random projection for biometric template protection},
        year={2010},
        pages={1-7},
        month={Sept},}

@TECHREPORT{nist,
    author = "C. I. Watson and M. D. Garris and E. Tabassi and 
    C. L. Wilson and R. M. McCabe and S. Janet and K. Ko",
    title = "User's guide to Non-Export Controlled Distribution of NIST Biometric Image Software",
    institution = "NIST",
    year = "2004"
}

@INPROCEEDINGS{ice,
    author={Phillips, P.J. and Bowyer, K.W. and Flynn, P.J. 
    and Liu, X. and Scruggs, W.T.},
    booktitle={2nd IEEE International Conference on Biometrics: Theory, Applications and Systems},
    title={The Iris Challenge Evaluation 2005},
    year={2008},
    month={Sept},
    pages={1-8},
}

  @MANUAL{fvc, 
    TITLE = "Fingerprint Verification Competition (FVC2002)", 
    NOTE = "http://bias.csr.unibo.it/fvc2002/databases.asp", 
    }
```

Comment: Please tell us *what exactly* isn't being formatted correctly. The authors' names, the publication title, the publication year, the form of the citation call-out, or something else? Please be very specific.

Comment: @Mico there are extra parenthesis coming in the conference citations

Comment: @Mico  I am getting a parenthesis in conf. citations and miscellaneous type citations. I have uploaded the image so that you can understand the whole issue.

Comment: @Mico these bib entries are:   @TECHREPORT{nist,
     author = "C. I. Watson and M. D. Garris and E. Tabassi and C. L. Wilson and R. M. McCabe and S. Janet and K. Ko",
     title = "User's guide to Non-Export Controlled Distribution of NIST Biometric Image Software",
     institution = "NIST",
     year = "2004"
    }     @MANUAL{fvc, 
     TITLE = "Fingerprint Verification Competition (FVC2002)", 
     NOTE = "http://bias.csr.unibo.it/fvc2002/databases.asp", 
     }

Comment: @Mico added the same into posting

Comment: I found I did not need the `")" *` on the _article_ formatting in the bst file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are so many errors and sloppy coding practices in the file `iet.bst`, it's hard to tell where one should start. One of them is particularly egregious; see below.

- Because of what are quite likely sloppy programming errors, many entry types *require* the presence of (non-empty) `address` and `year` fields. While requiring a `year` field doesn't seem that overbearing, the strict requirement for an `address` field is quite unusual, to say the least. Indeed, all four of the sample entries you provided need an `address` field. The address should be either the location of the organization that published the piece or the location of the conference.
- An even more severe programming error in the bst file cannot be glossed over simply by adding a normally-optional field such as `address`. I'm afraid you'll need to fix this error by editing the file `iet.bst` by hand, as follows:

  - Make a copy of the file `iet.bst` and call the copy, say, `iet-fixed.bst`.
  - Open the file `iet-fixed.bst` in a text editor. The editor you use for your tex file will do fine.
  - Find all lines that contain the string `"year" output.check`. (There are more than a dozen instances.) The first instance should be around line 1449, the last one should be around line 1787.)
  - In all but one of these cases, replace the string

    ```
    "year" output.check
    ```

    with

    ```
    "year" output.check ")" *
    ```

    i.e., append `")" *` to `"year" output.check`. In just one instance, the substring `")" *` is already present; *don't* append the substring in that case.
- While you're editing the bst file, you might as well fix another annoying programming error: Find the function `bbl.pages` -- it should start around line 557 -- and replace `"pp.~"` with `"pp."`, i.e., get rid of the tilde symbol.
- Save the file `iet-fixed.bst` to the directory that contains your main tex file.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{iet}` to `\bibliographystyle{iet-fixed}` and rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!

Here's an MWE which (a) utilizes the "fixed" version of the iet bibliography style and (b) has provided dummy `address` fields for all four entries. Do note that you should probably change the entry type of `fvc` from `@manual` to `@misc`. And, in the `nist` entry, do encase the acronym `NIST` in curly braces to prevent BibTeX from lowercasing the acronym.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@INPROCEEDINGS{byang,
author={B. Yang and D. Hartung and K. Simoens and C. Busch},
booktitle={IEEE International Conference on Biometrics: 
Theory Applications and Systems (BTAS)},
title={Dynamic random projection for biometric template protection},
address = "Somewhere",
year={2010},
pages={1-7},
month={Sept},
}
@TECHREPORT{nist,
author = "C. I. Watson and M. D. Garris and E. Tabassi and 
         C. L. Wilson and R. M. McCabe and S. Janet and K. Ko",
title  = "User's guide to Non-Export Controlled Distribution of 
         {NIST} Biometric Image Software",
institution = "NIST",
address = "Nowhere",
year = "2004",
}
@INPROCEEDINGS{ice,
author={Phillips, P. J. and Bowyer, K. W. and Flynn, P. J. 
    and Liu, X. and Scruggs, W. T.},
booktitle={2nd IEEE International Conference on Biometrics: Theory, Applications and Systems},
title={The {Iris Challenge Evaluation} 2005},
address="Erewhon",
year={2008},
month={Sept},
pages={1-8},
}
@misc{fvc, 
TITLE = "{Fingerprint Verification Competition} ({FVC2002})", 
NOTE = "\url{http://bias.csr.unibo.it/fvc2002/databases.asp}", 
address="Where",
year = 2002,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite} % <-- a basic citation management package
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces]{url} % <-- for decent-looking URL strings
\bibliographystyle{iet-fixed}

\begin{document}
\cite{nist}, \cite{byang}, \cite{ice}, \cite{fvc}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you sir...Almost all the problems have been solved except the one.  when i use the package \usepackage[hyphens,spaces]{url} for fvc (@misc) entry, the error appears: Option clash for package url.

Comment: @rudreshdwivedi - You must be using a document class that preloads the `url` package. Delete that `usepackage` statement, then, and insert the instruction`\RequirePackage[spaces,hyphens]{url}` *before* the `\documentclass` statement.

Comment: I have done the same. still the error appears: Option clash for package url. \usepackage

Comment: @rudreshdwivedi - Note that I suggested you write `\RequirePackage`, not `\usepackage`. Of course, any `\usepackage` instructions that load the `url` package somewhere else in the document's preamble should be deleted.

Answer (score -1):

Delete the parenthesis in the line 1290 of the original [`iet.bst`](http://digital-library.theiet.org/files/IET_ResearchJournals_latex.zip).