# \citeauthor in \documentclass{cta-author}

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I was using `\documentclass{article}`with

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,
    natbib=true,
    style=ieee,
    citestyle=numeric-comp,
    sorting=none,
    doi=false,
    isbn=false,
    url=true,
    %           minnames=1, % used for setting both minbibnames & mincitenames at a time
    %           maxnames=2,
    mincitenames=1, % used for setting min number of author names in text area
    maxcitenames=1,
    %           minbibnames=1,  % used for setting min number of author names in biblography/reference area
    %           maxbibenames=1,
    urldate=long,   %year(2016), short(08/30/2016), long(Aug. 30, 2016), terse(08/30/2016), comp(Aug. 30, 2016), iso8601(2016-08-30)
]{biblatex}
```

Which gives the last name of the first author and then *et al.* depending on the number of authors for `\citeauthor`.

Now I need to change the document class to: `cta-author`, for `IET`. Here I am restricted to use above settings (even not able to include `natbib`). MnWE is given below:

```
\documentclass{cta-author}
    \begin{document}
        \citeauthor{lesk:1977}

    \bibliographystyle{iet}
    \bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

The refs.bib file is taken from [here](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/532-creating-and-managing-bibliographies-with-bibtex-on-overleaf)

```
@book{latex2e,
  author = {Leslie Lamport},
  year = {1994},
  title = {\LaTeX: a Document Preparation System},
  publisher = {Addison Wesley},
  address = {Massachusetts},
  edition = {2}
}

@article{knuth:1984,
  title={Literate Programming},
  author={Donald E. Knuth},
  journal={The Computer Journal},
  volume={27},
  number={2},
  pages={97--111},
  year={1984},
  publisher={Oxford University Press}
}

@inproceedings{lesk:1977,
  title={Computer Typesetting of Technical Journals on {UNIX}},
  author={Michael Lesk and Brian Kernighan},
  booktitle={Proceedings of American Federation of
             Information Processing Societies: 1977
             National Computer Conference},
  pages={879--888},
  year={1977},
  address={Dallas, Texas}
}
```

Q: How to get `\citeauthor` behaviour as in `article` class?

[IET Latex template direct download link](http://digital-library.theiet.org/files/IET_Author-doublecolumn-submission.zip), [iet.bst file](https://github.com/mairasaboia/ratProj_animalBiometrics_iet_journal/blob/master/iet.bst)

Comment: Where can we get `iet.bst` and `cta-author`? (Is it the same as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/346204/35864?)

Comment: Probably yes, for convenience I added the direct link.

Comment: Usually I would recommend you try [`usebib`](https://ctan.org/pkg/usebib), but I'm not sure that `bibentry` parses names as required and depending on the submission procedure it might not be usable.

Comment: Good news is that the class uses `natbib` and that theoretically we could modify the `.bst` file in a way to allow for `\citeauthor` to work. I don't have time right now and maybe Mico steps up to the challenge, but if he doesn't I'll have a look at this later. Can't promise anything though.

Comment: Is the `iet` bibliography style compatible with `biblatex`? (I stongly doubt it...) If that's not the case, you'll have to switch from `biblatex` to BibTeX and a suitable citation management package. Good news: The `iet` bibliography style appears to be compatible with the `natbib` package.

Comment: No, It's not compatible, as in the first case, after changing only`\documentclass`, it produces few errors for `biblatex`. As shown in MnWE, it produces references with no error currently. The only problem remains is `\citeauthor`. I tried to add `\usepackage{natbib}` and `\citeauthor{lesk:1977}` it shows: **(author?)**, though no error.
As hinted by @moewe, using `\usepackage{usebib}`, `\newbibfield{author}`,`\bibinput{refs}`and`\usebibentry{lesk:1977}{author}` shows all text of author field, not as wanted: "last name of the first author and then *et al.* depending on the number of authors".

Comment: I just noticed that the `.zip` you linked does not contain `iet.bst`. Where can we get that, please?

Comment: link added for `iet.bst` file

Comment: OK, are sure that this second-hand source is actually the official `iet.bst` that should be used for submissions?

Comment: [This is official link](http://digital-library.theiet.org/files/IET_ResearchJournals_latex.zip)

Comment: Ah, I had found that earlier, but I had problems opening that `.zip` with Windows' built-in `.zip` utility, it worked with Peazip.

Comment: PeaZip is great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the class loads `natbib` it is incompatible with `biblatex`. Additionally, the submission process required a pasted `thebibliography` from the `.bbl`, that means `biblatex` is quite definitely out of the question.

Since `natbib`'s `\citeauthor` support depends only on the `.bst` style used, it is possible to hack `iet.bst` to get what you want. For submission you will replace the two lines

```
\bibliographystyle{iet}
\bibliography{refs}
```

with a copy of the contents of the `.bbl` file, so it does not cause additional technical complications to hack the `.bst` file.

You need to be aware of the possibility that even though `\citeauthor` works in the following it might not work as expected when the file is submitted to the journal. Publisher usually have a workflow to convert LaTeX documents into their own proprietary format. `\citeauthor` is probably not amongst the commands they expect, so it could go wrong at this point.

For copyright and length reasons I don't feel comfortable providing the `.bst` file here in its entirety. The following is the patch diff to the `iet.bst` (file date 2012-10-05, `sha256sum`: `56decf42e3f5cec42cb9f311b6abc868827dc7ccf9ac8e6d93273984dd25e2e1`) contained in http://digital-library.theiet.org/files/IET_ResearchJournals_latex.zip.

The patch also includes the fixes suggested by [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico) in [How to modify citation and database entry for conf. proceeding with this .bst?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/346204/35864).

The code for `natbib` author-year compatibility was taken in simplified form from Patrick W. Daly's `plainnat.bst`

```
--- iet.bst 2012-10-05 13:31:53.790000000 +0200
+++ iet-ay.bst  2018-07-05 13:50:00.796440800 +0200
@@ -1,3 +1,9 @@
+% iet-ay.bst
+% 2018-07-05
+% modified following Mico's suggestion in
+% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/346287/35864
+% and additionally for author-year citation support for
+% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/439309/35864
 ENTRY
   { address
     assignee     % for patents
@@ -34,7 +40,7 @@
     updated % urlbst
   }
   {}
-  { label }
+  { label short.list }
 %% Declaration of integer variables
 INTEGERS { output.state before.all mid.sentence after.sentence after.block }
 STRINGS { urlintro eprinturl eprintprefix doiprefix doiurl } % urlbst...
@@ -555,7 +561,7 @@
 { "in" }

 FUNCTION {bbl.pages}
-{ "pp.~" }
+{ "pp." }

 FUNCTION {bbl.page}
 { "p." }
@@ -889,10 +895,65 @@
   if$
 }

+FUNCTION {format.lab.names}
+{ 's :=
+  s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
+  s num.names$
+  #1 >
+    { " et~al." * }
+    'skip$
+  if$
+}
+
+FUNCTION {author.key.label}
+{ author empty$
+    { key empty$
+        { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
+        'key
+      if$
+    }
+    { author format.lab.names }
+  if$
+}
+
+FUNCTION {author.editor.key.label}
+{ author empty$
+    { editor empty$
+        { key empty$
+            { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
+            'key
+          if$
+        }
+        { editor format.lab.names }
+      if$
+    }
+    { author format.lab.names }
+  if$
+}
+
+FUNCTION {calc.label}
+{ author.editor.key.label 'short.list :=
+  short.list
+  "("
+  *
+  year duplicate$ empty$
+  short.list key field.or.null = or
+     { pop$ "" }
+     'skip$
+  if$
+  *
+  ")"
+  *
+  'label :=
+}
+
 FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
-{ outside.brackets 'bracket.state := % urlbst
+{ calc.label
+  outside.brackets 'bracket.state := % urlbst
    newline$
-  "\bibitem{" write$
+  "\bibitem["  write$
+  label  write$
+  "]{" write$
   cite$ write$
   "}" write$
   newline$
@@ -1503,7 +1564,7 @@
     %%{ inbrackets type output }
   if$
   format.publisher.address output
-  format.date "year" output.check
+  format.date "year" output.check ")" *
   new.block
   format.note output
   new.block
@@ -1595,7 +1656,7 @@
   format.edition output
   new.sentence
   format.publisher.address output
-  format.date "year" output.check
+  format.date "year" output.check ")" *
   format.btitle "title" output.check
   add.semicolon
   add.blank
@@ -1618,7 +1679,7 @@
   new.sentence
   format.number.series output
   format.publisher.address output
-  format.date "year" output.check
+  format.date "year" output.check ")" *
   date.block
   add.blank
   format.pages "pages" output.check
@@ -1640,7 +1701,7 @@
   new.sentence
   format.number.series output
   format.publisher.address output
-  format.date "year" output.check
+  format.date "year" output.check ")" *
   date.block
   add.blank
   format.pages "pages" output.check
@@ -1666,7 +1727,7 @@
       format.publisher.address output
     }
   if$
-  format.date "year" output.check
+  format.date "year" output.check ")" *
   date.block
   add.blank
   format.pages "pages" output.check
@@ -1734,7 +1795,7 @@
       if$
      }
   if$
-      format.date "year" output.check
+      format.date "year" output.check ")" *
   new.block
   format.note output
   output.web.refs  % urlbst
@@ -1765,7 +1826,7 @@
   "title" output.check
   format.type "type" output.check
   new.block
-  format.publisher.address output
+  format.publisher.address output ")" *
   format.date "year" output.check
   new.block
   format.note output
```

Using the new `iet-ay.bst` the MWE

```
\documentclass{cta-author}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{latex2e,
  author    = {Leslie Lamport},
  year      = {1994},
  title     = {\LaTeX: a Document Preparation System},
  publisher = {Addison Wesley},
  address   = {Massachusetts},
  edition   = {2}
}

@article{knuth:1984,
  title     = {Literate Programming},
  author    = {Donald E. Knuth},
  journal   = {The Computer Journal},
  volume    = {27},
  number    = {2},
  pages     = {97--111},
  year      = {1984},
  publisher = {Oxford University Press}
}

@inproceedings{lesk:1977,
  title     = {Computer Typesetting of Technical Journals on {UNIX}},
  author    = {Michael Lesk and Brian Kernighan},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of American Federation of
               Information Processing Societies: 1977
               National Computer Conference},
  pages     = {879--888},
  year      = {1977},
  address   = {Dallas, Texas}
}

@book{companion,
  author       = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
  title        = {The {LaTeX} Companion},
  year         = 1994,
  edition      = 1,
  publisher    = {Addison-Wesley},
  address      = {Reading, Mass.},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
  \citeauthor{lesk:1977}

  \citeauthor{knuth:1984}

  \citeauthor{latex2e}

  \citeauthor{companion}

  \bibliographystyle{iet-ay}
  \bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]