# How to \citeauthor without switching to \bibliographystyle{plainnat}?

Tags: citing, natbib, ieee-style

I know there are a few questions regarding this, but I couldn't find the solution specifically for such problem: how do I `\citeauthor{}`, but keep the citing style that I want (I use `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}`).

My .tex file looks something like this:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\citeauthor{smith}

\begin{document}
    \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
    \bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

And .bib file:

```
@Article{smth,
author ="Smith, Anton",
title  ="The title",
year  ="2019",
journal = "Some journal",
volume  ="1"}
```

I get the (**author ?**) instead of Anton.

So how would I keep my citing style but use `\citeauthor`?

Comment: The `ieeetr` BibTeX style does not provide author and year information to `natbib`. So you can't use `\citeauthor` with it. It is theoretically possible to modify the style in a way to allow for author-year information being passed on, but that is a bit of work. If you have to use `ieeetr` there should be no pressing need to use `\citeauthor`. If you need `\citeauthor` it might be better to start using a different style (you don't have to use `plainnat`, a number of other styles also pass on author-year info to `natbib`).

Comment: In https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/439309/35864 it is shown how one can transplant `plainnat`'s author-year info into a different style (`iet.bst`). The general procedure should be the same, but details could be different.

Comment: I see. Thank you @moewe. Could you recommend a style, similar to ieeetr, which passes author-year information to natbib?

Comment: @laukinisgyvunelis - Please see the answer I just posted: Use the `IEEEtranN` bibliography style.

Comment: @moewe - Fortunately, the IEEE has provided sensible successors to the meanwhile prehistoric `ieeetr` bib style. If the author wants to use the machinery of the `natbib` package while keeping the distinctive IEEE "look" for formatted bibliographies, he/she should switch to the `IEEEtranN` bib style.

Answer (score 7):

The `ieeetr` bibliography style is more than thirty [30!] years old. Fortunately, the IEEE has come up with newer bib styles in recent years which (i) more or less produce the same formatted bibliographies and (ii) interact nicely with modern citation management packages, such as `natbib`.

In particular, if you want to be able to use the `\citeauthor` macro of the `natbib` package, you should switch to the `IEEEtranN` bib style. Its output, using the MWE file below, is as follows:

[image]

For comparison, this is what's produced if the ancient `ieeetr` bib style is used -- note the "(**author**?)" string in the place where the screenshot above shows "Smith" :

[image]

As you can see, the entry of type `@article` is formatted identically by both bib styles -- the difference is in how `\citeauthor{smith}` is processed.

Do also note that the `natbib` package should be loaded with the option `numbers` if one of the `IEEEtranX` bib styles is employed.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{References.bib}
@article{smith,
author  = "Smith, Anton",
title   = "The title",
year    = "2019",
journal = "Some journal",
volume  = "1",
number  = "2",
pages   = "3--4",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN} %%% or: \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}

\begin{document}
\cite{smith}, \citeauthor{smith}    
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In case you're curious about what I had in mind when I wrote that the old and new bib styles "more or less produce the same formatted bibliographies": the recent `IEEEtran`, `IEEEtranN`, etc bibliography styles do *not* ignore fields such as `url`  and `doi`. In contrast, the ancient `ieeetr` style, which predates the inception of the world wide web by a decade or more, doesn't even know what to do with these fields and hence simply ignores them.