# How to cite author's name in a research paper?

Tags: natbib, ieeetran

I try to add the author's name of a paper to describe their contributions.
But it does not work:

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\citeauthor{24}
```

This is the output of my pdf looks like this: "(author?)"

I'm using

```
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
```

Comment: Either your entry for `24` does not have a valid `author` field or you are using a bibliography style that is not compatible with `natbib`'s author-year citations. Can you tell us which `\bibliograpyhstyle` you use? Styles that would work include `plainnat`, `unsrtnat`, `abbrvnat`, ...

Comment: Dear @moewe, this is the style that I am using. \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}

Comment: `ieeetr` is not compatible with `natbib`, try `IEEEtranN` instead: `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}`.

Comment: @moewe thank you but it does not work I still have the same error.

Comment: You need to run LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX again on your document. If it still does not work for you, please show us a complete example document: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/479424/35864

Comment: @moewe it works finally thank you