# error-command \c@refsection already defined

Tags: biblatex, errors, natbib

I'm using the IET template(https://digital-library.theiet.org/journals/author-guide). The error information also tell incompatible with natbib? Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

```
\documentclass{cta-author}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}{}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}{}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}{}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{iet} 
\bibliography{aaa}  

\cite{boulkenafet2017face}

\end{document}
```

[image: error information]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You can not use `biblatex` together with `\bibliographystyle`. Simply comment `biblatex` in your code ...

Comment: Related (half-duplicate): https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/439309/35864

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a newer version of `biblatex` the first error I get from your example is slightly more helpful than the errors shown in your screenshot.

```
! Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'natbib'.

See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

The class `cta-author` loads `natbib` for citations and the bibliography. (The example file then proceeds to add the references manually in `thebibliography` and does not provide any author-year metadata in a `natbib`-readable format, so the class does not make use of many of `natbib`'s most valued functions, but the package is still loaded.) `natbib` and `biblatex` are completely incompatible and can not be used together in the same document. Since your template loads `natbib`, the viable option is to stop using `biblatex`. Indeed, not a lot of publishers are known for accepting `biblatex` submissions and `biblatex` usually requires a different workflow ([Biblatex: submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864)).

In the example it should be enough to drop `biblatex` to make it work again (assuming you have the file `iet.bst`).

```
\documentclass{cta-author}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}{}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}{}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}{}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{iet} 
\bibliography{aaa}

\cite{boulkenafet2017face}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It should  be noted that (at least some versions of) `iet.bst` seem to be of very dubious quality: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/346204/35864. They also do not support `natbib`'s `author-year` features: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/439309/35864

Comment: very clear answer, thank you so much ! After I delete the \usepackage biblatex, I get the biber warning "No data sources defined". I change biber to bibtex according to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424603/, and it works well. Thank you again! ❤