# Why is a '(' appearing in citation while using @inproceedings and @misc entry in .bib file?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am making a `.bib` file and the citations are working well using `@article`. While using `@inproceedings` and `@misc`, I am getting one '(' in the reference.

```
@inproceedings{Aggarwal06,
   author={Aggarwal, Gagan and Hartline, Jason D.},
   year={2006},
   title={Knapsack auctions},
   booktitle={Proceedings of the 17th Annual ACM-SIAM Symposium on Discrete Algorithms},
   pages={1083-1092},
   publisher={Association for Computing Machinery},
   address={New York}
}
```

The result is coming out to be:

> Aggarwal, G., Hartline, J.D.   ‘Knapsack auctions’.   In: Proceedings of the 17thAnnual ACM-SIAM Symposium on Discrete Algorithms. (New York: Associationfor Computing Machinery, 2006. pp.  1083–1092.

**Notice the '(' before New York.**

I am using IET Trans format. So, using `iet.bst` file for bibliography style. Following is the link that I am using: [github.com/mairasaboia/ratProj_animalBiometrics_iet_journal](https://github.com/mairasaboia/ratProj_animalBiometrics_iet_journal)

Could anyone suggest how to get rid of this?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example?
Would be useful to see the natbib options and the bibliography style you are using.

Comment: Thanks. I am using IET Trans format. So, using iet.bst file for bibliography style. Following is the link that I am using: https://github.com/mairasaboia/ratProj_animalBiometrics_iet_journal

Comment: File `iet.bst` has a bug. Please make a bug report to the maintainer ...

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out. I have been able to make the correction by adding output.check in the both the entries: @ inproceedings and @ misc. The problem is resolved. I would notify the maintainer to make the edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complete solution consists of contacting the author/maintainer of the `iet` bibliography style.

Assuming that you don't want or need the `(` symbol before the address field, a temporary fix is available as follows. (Aside: If you do want to keep the opening parenthesis and wish to have a closing parenthesis immediately *after* the `year` field, I suggest you follow the instructions provided in [this earlier answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/346287/5001).)

- Make a copy of the file `iet.bst` and call the copy, say, `iet-fixed.bst`. (Don't modify `iet.bst` directly.)
- Open the file `iet-fixed.bst` in a text editor; the program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- In `iet-fixed.bst`, search for the following line:

  ```
  FUNCTION {format.org.or.pub}
  ```

  Two lines down from that line, you should find the following line:

  ```
  "("
  ```

  Change it to

  ```
  " "
  ```

  i.e., change the opening parenthesis to a space character.
- Save the file `iet-fixed.bst` either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{iet}` to `\bibliographystyle{iet-fixed}`. Then, perform a full recompile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more -- to propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!

---

Here's the output from a full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
%% Source of the following information:
%% https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1109677
@inproceedings{Aggarwal06,
  author       = "Aggarwal, Gagan and Hartline, Jason D.",
  title        = "Knapsack Auctions",
  booktitle    = "Proceedings of the Seventeenth Annual
                  ACM-SIAM Symposium on Discrete
                  Algorithms (SODA)",
  year         = 2006,
  isbn         = "0-89871-605-5",
  location     = "Miami, Florida",
  pages        = "1083--1092",
  numpages     = 10,
  url          = "http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1109557.1109677",
  acmid        = 1109677,
  publisher    = "SIAM",
  address      = "Philadelphia",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article} 
\bibliographystyle{iet-fixed}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
\cite{Aggarwal06}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```